# Why is the largest index is so much lower than the number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm studying the following tutorial, in which the excel file consists of 3 sheets with same data structure. When all of the sheets are put together using pandas.concat(), I observe that the number of the the rows in the dataframe created is different and so much larger than the last index in.

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/

I use pandas.shape to display the number of the rows, and pandas.tail() to print 5 rows from the end.
Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd


excel_file = "movies.xls"

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)

movies_sheets = []
for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
    movies_sheets.append(xlsx.parse(sheet))

[enter image description here][1]movies = pd.concat(movies_sheets)

print(movies.shape)
print(movies.tail())
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if use:

```
movies = pd.concat(movies_sheets)
```

it not create default index, only concat all 3 index values for each sheetname.

For prevent it add `ignore_index=True` parameter to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
movies = pd.concat(movies_sheets, ignore_index=True)
```

Or create default index:

```
movies = pd.concat(movies_sheets).reset_index(drop=True)
```